# How to set Firefox to log in to Stack Exchange chat

Tags: support, chat, firefox, noscript

I cannot log in to Stack Exchange chat.

If I check the [Login help page](https://chat.stackexchange.com/help), I get the following error.

> Test 5: Communication with stackauth.com – failed
>
> - IFRAMEs – ok
> - Referrer – ok
> - JavaScript – ok
> - Storage – ok
>
> We were not able to communicate with
> stackauth.com. Please make sure that
> you allow embedding of `<iframe>`s from
> remote sites into web pages, and that
> you allow this site and stackauth.com
> to communicate with each other.

I use Firefox 8 with [NoScript](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noscript/) and [RefControl](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/refcontrol/) extensions, so I guess I have somehow to appropriately set referrers.

### Update:

I have tried to enable and disable those two extensions in combination:

- If *RefControl* is enabled, regardless of activation status for *NoScript*, the result is as described above;
- If *RefControl* is disabled, regardless of activation status for *NoScript*, the result for referrer check is KO;

How do I fix this problem?

Is it possible to login to chat with Firefox 8?

Comment: Doesn't it work if you whitelist both domains in both extensions? (I don't know RefControl)

Comment: By "KO", do you mean "OK"? In other words, you can log in? Then it's clear that it's RefControl that is making your browser misbehave. Btw, there are many people who can login to chat with FF4 -- including myself. If you positively have to use a broken browser -- does the IE7 ghetto login work? http://askubuntu.com/users/chat-stackexchange-login

Comment: @balpha With KO I mean KO (Indeed I installed RefControl appropriately to make sites such as Launchpad or StackExchange chat to work). Clicking the link in your comment above, I get this: http://chat.stackexchange.com/login/global-fallback

Answer (score 3):

I succeeded in logging here with noscript and Requestpolicy (similar to RefControl). The most important is to ask for alternative authentification, then to enter https://openid.stackexchange.com in the openid field.

I have whitelisted in noscript:

```
ajax.googleapi.com, stackexchange.com, sstatic.net, the hostname hosting the question and answer sites you are posting on.
```

`sstatic.net` is only necessary for chat rooms.
None of them are necessary to post an answer or to log in.

I have whitelisted in Requestpolicy:

```
stackexchange.com, ajax.googleapi.com, stackauth.com, google.com, sstatic.net.
```

`google.com` is for the [periodic captcha](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209460/stack-overflow-knows-i-am-a-robot-and-greets-me-in-robot-language) checking that you are not a robot.
`sstatic.net` is for up-down voting, it is not necessary just to post answers.
`stackexchange.com, ajax.googleapi.com and stackauth.com` are not necessary just to post answers. 
`stackauth.com` is not necessary to make the inbox icon work.

Note: I am updating this post by taking out one by one elements from the whitelist. If it does not work for your config, look for second revisions of this post (and then add comments about your config).

Comment: Note that StackExchange does not use CSP (last I checked), so whitelisting them isn't necessarily a silver bullet.

Answer (score 2):

Add `stackauth.com` domain to the NoScript exception list.

Comment: stackauth.com is already in my exception list.

Comment: you should comment on why it did not work for igi.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be a direct answer to your question, yet I'll post this answer because I've encountered the same login problem using the **ScriptNo** extension for Google Chrome.

#### My settings

- whitelist

  - `*.stackauth.com`
  - `*.stackexchange.com`
- respect same domain (preserve same-domain elements): disabled
- sort by domain (sorts URL lists by domains): enabled
- Referrer Spoof: Off
- Block Click-Through Referrer: enabled

In my case, I had *referrer spoof* set to same domain. Changing it to *off* solved my problem.

#### Other

AdBlock can also cause login problems - I don't really know why. But by trial-and-error I found that adding the following elemets to the list where AdBlock is disabled helps:

```
@@||stackexchange.com/$document
@@||chat.stackexchange.com/$document
```

Answer (score 1):

Since test 3 has succeeded (otherwise test 5 wouldn't even run), and all the in-IFRAME tests are okay, this suggests you have enabled same-domain `postMessage`, but disabled it for cross-domain communication.

Comment: I looked for this cannot of settings in both extension, tricking as much as I could. No success...

Comment: @igi have you tried turning the extension off by one and testing again? That would at least tell you which of the two it is.

Comment: done; no improvement. Question updated according results I found.

Comment: NoScript disables XSS (Cross-Site Scripting) by default.  If you whitelist *.stackexchange.com, or tell NoScript to not activate on stackexchange.com, then it should work.  I ran into this issue myself.

Comment: Please update your answer with why this did [not](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117438/how-to-set-firefox-to-log-in-to-stack-exchange-chat/117439#comment307697_117440) work for user igi.