# Google Chrome says third party cookie not allowed, cannot login then

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting “Third Party Cookies Appear To Be Disabled” in Google Chrome](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138975/getting-third-party-cookies-appear-to-be-disabled-in-google-chrome)

Yesterday I tried to login to Stack Overflow through Stack Exchange account and there pops an error message that says "third party cookie not allowed". What is wrong with it.

Comment: @Bhuvan Rikka,  the question is about Stackoverflow so it is on topic.

Comment: see this http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138975/173001

Comment: I will check the link provided by Lucifer and let you know by tomorrow if it works ; )